# Why TCP_NODELAY option has no effect on linux 3.2.40?

Tags: linux, sockets

Why the following code can't turn off Nagle Algorithm:

```
int on = 1;
int ret = 0;
ret = setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &on, sizeof(on));
```

My program runs on linux kernel 3.2.40(maybe modified).

Thanks!

The following picture is a packet captured by wireshark, please focus on the red rectangle: 
    string BP01_2_S_1, BP01_3_S_1 and BP01_4_S_1(sorry, I can't include the angular brackets)
should be contained in 3 separate TCP packets(I call `send' 3 times), but now they are in the same packet, it's not what I want.

[image]

Comment: The code looks fine -- what leads you to believe it doesn't work?

Comment: What was the value of 'rc' when you check it after calling 'setsockopt()'? And why do you want three separate packets? Is your receiver coded improperly?

Comment: @EJP, YES, `ret' of setsockopt is ZERO, and my receiver is coded improperly(the receiver is coded by another guy).